# Since setOldSku(String oldSku) is depreciated

Tags: java, android, play-billing-library

Since  setOldSku(String oldSku) is depreciated, how to get the purchasetoken and pass it in the new method of setOldSk?

```
 public void initiatePurchaseFlow(final SkuDetails skuDetails, final String oldSkuId) {
    Runnable purchaseFlowRequest = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, " SKU Details: " + skuDetails.getTitle());
            BillingFlowParams purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails).setOldSku(oldSkuId, myPurchaseToken).build();
            mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity);
        }
    };

    executeServiceRequest(purchaseFlowRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this method with deprecated and use **ProrationMode** as per your requirements.

[Learn more about ProrationMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode#IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION)

```js
private fun updatePurchase(skuDetails: SkuDetails) {
   val updateParams = BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
       .setOldSkuPurchaseToken("oldPurchaseToken")
       .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE)
       .build()
 
   val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
       .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
       .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(updateParams)
       .build()
 
   billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams)
}
```

below method for newer billing lib

Answer (score -7):

Just downgrade it to 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1' for the time being.